# My sound won't play in a .jar file

Tags: java

Here is the code for my sound. It only works in Eclipse and not in a .jar file

```
try {
     InputStream defaultSound = Game.class.getResourceAsStream("/TrailsGameMusic.wav");
     // getClass().getSy.getResource("/images/ads/WindowsNavigationStart.wav");

     System.out.println("defaultSound " + defaultSound);  // check the URL!
     AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(defaultSound);
     Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
     clip.open(audioInputStream);
     clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
} catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I fixed this by adding a sound called sound and doing this

```
sound = new Sound("res\\TrailsGameMusic.wav");
```

Answer (score 1):

`Game.class.getResourceAsStream("/TrailsGameMusic.wav");` uses the class loader to locate the file, so in general, file must be on class path.  If path starts with "/", then file name is relative to root of classes in the jar file, so put this file in the jar at the top level.  My guess is that this in the root folder for the project, which is the default location for Eclipse.

Comment: yes it is in a folder called res that is a source folder for the project

Comment: then try `Game.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/TrailsGameMusic.wav");`

Comment: it only works with a res folder next to it. i want it to work on its own

Comment: not sure what you mean "on its own".  Not embedded in jar?